# let OS take over for specific key bindings?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm working with OS X Lion and have key bindings which allow me to switch screens in VirtualBox and Language Input, and so on. I wonder if I can include something in my `.emacs` file which will allow the OS to take over for certain bindings, e.g., `C-<right>`, `C-K`, etc. rather than Emacs giving me an error that these combinations are undefined?

Comment: Which version of Emacs are you using in OS X? Are you setting the keyboard shortcuts from System Preferences->Keyboard->Keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: It is 24.1.1. Most of my keyboard shortcuts are set in my `.emacs` file. What can I set in System Preferences->Keyboard->Keyboard that isn't overridden by Emacs?

Comment: I don't know Mac OS X enough to answer, but usually the "OS keybindings" take precedence, so there's nothing Emacs can do.  If Mac 
OS X also provides "default bindings" which the application can override, then you might `M-x report-emacs-bug` and ask for the corresponding feature to be added.

Comment: It may well be something you have considered and rejected already, but Aquamacs is a flavour of Emacs that offers many interesting ways to work with the OS.  I use it on an old Lion computer.